# Pass type of array element to function

Tags: typescript

I have a React component that takes an array of any type e.g.

```
type Props = {
  options: any[];
  renderItem: (any, i) => ReactNode
}
```

How do I edit the types such that the type of the first argument of `renderItem` is the element type of the `options` array?

Answer (score 1):

Make the whole type generic. Something like:

```
type Props<T extends unknown> = {
  options: T[];
  renderItem: (value: T, i: number) => ReactNode
}
```

Comment: Can TS derive the type of T automatically or do you have to explicitly mention the type?

Comment: I think you have to explicitly note it, but I'm not 100% sure if there might sometimes be a way around it.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a solution where you could pass the options array argument and renderItem would automatically know the type of the options array